# What is the meaning of $0 = $0 in Awk?

Tags: awk

While going through a piece of code I saw the below command:

```
grep "r" temp | awk '{FS=","; $0=$0} { print $1,$3}'
```

temp file contain the pattern like:

```
 1. r,1,5
 2. r,4,5
 3. ...
```

I could not understand what does the statement `$0=$0` mean in awk command.

Can anyone explain what does it mean?

Comment: The script looks broken to me. More common is to use `$1 = $1` to "touch" the line and reformat it, separating each field with the `OFS` (a single space by default). Have you tried removing it?

Comment: @TomFenech its not exactly "broken", it's a cludge due to FS being set AFTER the first record is read to case field splitting to occur even for that first record.

Comment: @Ed ah, so if I understand correctly, assigning to `$0` has the side effect of `$1`, `$2`, etc. being modified, whereas assigning to a specific field has the side effect of the whole record `$0` being modified.

Comment: Right, and NF is modified by $0=$0 but not by $1=$1. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41941143/1745001.

Answer (score 7):

When you do `$1=$1` (or any other assignment to a field) it causes record recompilation where $0 is rebuilt with every FS replaced with OFS but it does not change NF (unless there was no `$1` previously and then NF would change from 0 to 1) or reevaluate the record in any other way.

When you do `$0=$0` it causes field splitting where NF, $1, $2, etc. are repopulated based on the current value of FS but it does not change the FSs to OFSs or modify $0 in any other way.

Look:

```
$ echo 'a-b-c' |
    awk -F'-+' -v OFS='-' '
        function p() { printf "%d) %d: $0=%s, $2=%s\n", ++c,NF,$0,$2 }
        { p(); $2=""; p(); $1=$1; p(); $0=$0; p(); $1=$1; p() }
    '
1) 3: $0=a-b-c, $2=b
2) 3: $0=a--c, $2=
3) 3: $0=a--c, $2=
4) 2: $0=a--c, $2=c
5) 2: $0=a-c, $2=c
```

Note in the above that even though setting $2 to null resulted in 2 consecutive `-`s and the FS of `-+` means that 2 `-`s are a single separator, they are not treated as such until `$0=$0` causes the record to be re-split into fields as shown in output step 4.

The code you have:

```
awk '{FS=","; $0=$0}'
```

is using `$0=$0` as a cludge to work around the fact that it's not setting FS until AFTER the first record has been read and split into fields:

```
$ printf 'a,b\nc,d\n' | awk '{print NF, $1}'
1 a,b
1 c,d

$ printf 'a,b\nc,d\n' | awk '{FS=","; print NF, $1}'
1 a,b
2 c

$ printf 'a,b\nc,d\n' | awk '{FS=","; $0=$0; print NF, $1}'
2 a
2 c
```

The correct solution, of course, is instead to simply set FS BEFORE The first record is read:

```
$ printf 'a,b\nc,d\n' | awk -F, '{print NF, $1}'
2 a
2 c
```

To be clear - assigning any value to $0 causes field splitting, it does not cause record recompilation while assigning any value to any field ($1, etc.) causes record recompilation but not field splitting:

```
$ echo 'a-b-c' | awk -F'-+' -v OFS='#' '{$2=$2}1'
a#b#c
$ echo 'a-b-c' | awk -F'-+' -v OFS='#' '{$0=$0}1'
a-b-c
```

Answer (score 3):

`$0 = $0` is used most often to rebuild the field separation evaluation of a modified entry. Ex: adding a field will change $NF after $0 = $0 where it stay as original (at entry of the line).

in this case, it <del>change every line the field separator by `,` and</del> (*see @EdMorton comment below for strike*) reparse the line with current FS info where a `awk -F ',' { print $1 "," $3 }'` is a lot better coding for the same idea, taking the field separator at begining for all lines (in this case, could be different if separator is modified during process depernding by example of previous line content)

ex:

```
echo "foo;bar" | awk '{print NF}{FS=";"; print NF}{$0=$0;print NF}'
1
1
2
```

based on @EdMorton comment and related post ([What is the meaning of $0 = $0 in Awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932996/what-is-the-meaning-of-0-0-in-awk/41941143#41941143))

```
echo "a-b-c" |\
awk ' BEGIN{ FS="-+"; OFS="-"}
   function p(Ref) { printf "%12s) NF=%d $0=%s, $2=%s\n", Ref,NF,$0,$2 }
   {
   p("Org")
   $2="-"; p( "S2=-")
   $1=$1 ; p( "$1=$1")
   $2=$2 ; p( "$2=$2")
   $0=$0 ; p( "$0=$0")
   $2=$2 ; p( "$2=$2")
   $3=$3 ; p( "$3=$3")
   $1=$1 ; p( "$1=$1")
   } '

  Org) NF=3 $0=a-b-c, $2=b
 S2=-) NF=3 $0=a---c, $2=-
$1=$1) NF=3 $0=a---c, $2=-
$2=$2) NF=3 $0=a---c, $2=-
$0=$0) NF=2 $0=a---c, $2=c
$2=$2) NF=2 $0=a-c, $2=c
$3=$3) NF=3 $0=a-c-, $2=c
$1=$1) NF=3 $0=a-c-, $2=c
```

Comment: no, the record is reconstituted by using `$1 = $1`. Using `$0 = $0` does not trigger it.

Comment: @fedorqui, i just retest to be sur, this is (on my linux, so gawk) `$0=$0`the trigger (see added info on my post)

Comment: Neron: ok, you are absolutely right. From [GNU awk on Changing Fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Changing-Fields): _Any assignment to $0 causes the record to be reparsed into fields using the current value of FS_. It is weird, though, since a bit above it mentions `$1=$1` as the way to force the record to be reconstituted.

Comment: @fedorqui & NeronLeVu you're both confusing record recompilation and field splitting. `$0=$0` WILL NOT change the field separator, it WILL resplit the record into fields. By contrast `$1=$1` WILL change the field separator, it WILL NOT resplit the record into fields. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41941143/1745001

Comment: @EdMorton what do you mean by *will change* ? Separator change is done via FS and OFS but effective separation (meaning field attribution) is done with $0= (or next line/record) by reevaluate the full line as a whole (where empty field are no more *existing*) . The $1= rebuild the output based on field content (where empty field are not null field) and adapt NF. I add sample based on your other good post you mention

Comment: By *will change* I just mean exactly that - every FS in the current record will change to an OFS when you do `$1=$1`. You say in your answer `in this case it change every line the field separator by ,` - no, `FS=","; $0=$0` doesn't change the line at all you'd need to add `$1=$1` or similar to change the line.

Comment: @EdMorton ok, reply adapted with your comment

Answer (score 1):

`$0=$0`  is for re-evaluate the fields

**For example**

```
akshay@db-3325:~$ cat <<EOF | awk '/:/{FS=":"}/\|/{FS="|"}{print $2}'
1:2
2|3
EOF


# Same with $0=$0, it will force awk to have the $0 reevaluated

akshay@db-3325:~$ cat <<EOF | awk '/:/{FS=":"}/\|/{FS="|"}{$0=$0;print $2}'
1:2
2|3
EOF
2
3

# NF - gives you the total number of fields in a record
akshay@db-3325:~$ cat <<EOF | awk '/:/{FS=":"}/\|/{FS="|"}{print NF}'
1:2
2|3
EOF

1
1

# When we Force to re-evaluate the fields, we get correct 2 fields
akshay@db-3325:~$ cat <<EOF | awk '/:/{FS=":"}/\|/{FS="|"}{$0=$0; print NF}'
1:2
2|3
EOF

2
2
```

Comment: Can you comment on why was the field separator ignored in the first command(cat <<EOF | awk '/:/{FS=":"}/\|/{FS="|"}{print $2}') and then we needed to put $0=$0 to re-evaluate?

Comment: Because `$0=$0` re-evaluate fields, in first example, `awk` thinks that default field separate `1 space` is used, even though there is `:` and `|` for the pattern matched.  so we get nothing when we print `$2`, but after `$0=$0` it re-evaluates and prints correctly

Comment: why does "awk think that default field separate 1 space is used, even though there is : and |" ?

Comment: Because we did not set field sep in beginning either by `-F` or in `BEGIN` block or as an argument, so uses default field sep 1 space. See difference run these command `echo 1,2,3,4,5 | awk '{FS=","; print $2}'` gives nothing, whereas `echo 1,2,3,4,5 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{ print $2}'` or  `echo 1,2,3,4,5 | awk -F, '{ print $2}'` or `echo 1,2,3,4,5 | awk '{ print $2}' FS=","`  or  `echo 1,2,3,4,5 | awk '{FS=","; $0=$0; print $2}'` you get 2

Comment: In short you have set in the beginning which field sep is used  or else run time use `$0=$0` to re-evaluate fields

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> echo 'a-b-c' | awk -F'-+' -v OFS='#' '{$2=$2}1' 
>>> a#b#c
```

This can be slightly simplified to

```
mawk 'BEGIN { FS="[-]+"; OFS = "#"; } ($2=$2)'
```

Rationale being the boolean test that comes afterwards will evaluate to true upon the assignment, so that itself is sufficient to re-gen the fields in OFS and print it.