# How include second awk to avoid awk | awk

Tags: bash, awk

This is the input string:

```
status=N&Cau=1&Litrs=0&Freq=0&Min=0
```

and this is the awk to extract values and parse into csv: (That work but could be better..)

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="&"}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="="} {printf("%s;"),$2}'
```

Result is:

```
N;1;0;0;0;
```

The question is: Is there any way to do it in a single awk? ( Not awk | awk)

First line in CSV will be:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="&"}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="="} {printf("%s;"),$1}'
status;Cau;Litrs;Freq;Min;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one setting `OFS` and `FS` and then using the `$1=$1` [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41941143/2229272) to reconstitute `$0`, with a bit of final massaging to move the first `;` to the end.

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=";"; FS="(^|&)[^&]*=" } { $1=$1; print substr($0,2)";" }'
N;1;0;0;0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean...you could do something like:

```
awk -F'&' '
{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    split($i, x, "=")
    values[i]=x[2]
  }
  
  for (i=1; i<=length(values); i++) {
    printf "%s;", values[i]
  }
}
'
```

But I don't know if that's much of an improvement!

Answer (score 0):

If your input is only one line -- and it looks like it might be because you're parsing a URL -- you could use this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="="; RS="&"} {sub(/\n$/,"",$2); printf "%s;", $2} END {printf "\n";}'
```

This recognizes that the input is simply records and fields separated in a different way than newlines and spaces -- so by changing the field separator to `=` and the record separator to `&`, each `xx=N` segment is processed as if it were a separate line, with `$2` equal to `N`. So we just print, for every record, `$2` followed by the semicolon. However if you have a newline at the end of the input line, which you probably do, that fouls up the last record, which is why the `sub(/\n$/,"",$2);` is needed, the remove any newline. The `END` clause supplies an ending newline.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the desired result is a 2-line set of output:

```
status;Cau;Litrs;Freq;Min;             # header record
N;1;0;0;0;                             # data record
```

One idea using a single `awk` invocation (to replace the current set of 4x `awk` invocations):

```
indat="status=N&Cau=1&Litrs=0&Freq=0&Min=0"    # assuming OP has data in a variable

awk -F'[&=]' '                                 # define "&" and "=" as input field separators
     { for (i=1 ; i<NF ; i=i+2)                # loop through the odd numbers
           { hdr=hdr $(i) ";"                  # build header record from odd # fields
             dat=dat $(i+1) ";"                # build data record from even # fields
           }
     }
END  { printf "%s\n%s\n", hdr, dat }           # dump our 2 records to stdout
' <<< "${indat}"                               # feed input variable via a here string
```

This generates:

```
status;Cau;Litrs;Freq;Min;
N;1;0;0;0;
```

If the (eventual) intention is to build a CSV file with several lines of data (eg, input will come from a stream of parsed URL's) then it shouldn't be too hard to build/print the `hdr` variable when `FNR==1`; additionally we'd want to a) clear `dat` before the `for` loop and b) print `dat` after the `for` loop; etc, etc, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly enhanced the solution proposed by **jas**. now the syntax will self resolve the delimiter up front, and lack of delimiter on the back. It also doesn't need to use gensub(), so it's fully mawk compatible (or any sub/gsub for that matter)

As ugly as all those regex appear requiring explicit declaration for all 4 major variables, all the processing is already accomplished there, plus the $1=$1 trick.

```
mawk 'BEGIN { FS = "&[^=]+="; OFS = ";"; RS = "^[^=]+=|\n"; ORS = ";\n"; } ( $1 = $1 )'
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the 2-line solution, it's a combination of tricks :

```
mawk 'BEGIN { OFS = ";"; FS = "=[^&]*(&|$)"; } 
            { save0 = $0; sub(/^[^=]+=/, "", save0); } 
            { $1 = $1; print; }
            { FS = "&[^=]+="; $0 = save0; } (NF++)'
```

(Technically there's no need to split them into { } groups i just wrote it as such to make it easier to read)

To make it multi-line friendly, update FS towards the end of it, like

```
mawk 'BEGIN { OFS = ";"; FS = "=[^&]*(&|$)"; } 
            { save0 = $0; sub(/^[^=]+=/, "", save0); } 
            { $1 = $1; print; }
            { FS = "&[^=]+="; $0 = save0; FS="=[^&]*(&|$)"; } (NF++)'
```