# convert a character from row to column using shell command

Tags: bash, shell

How do i convert a character from row to column in a shell scripting or command.
example:
input: HELLO

i want output:

```
H
E
L
L
O
```

I tried with tr command . But it doesn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`

```
echo "HELLO" | awk -v FS= -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1'
```

---

Or

```
awk -v FS= -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1'  <<< 'HELLO'
```

Comment: What's the logic of `{$1=$1}1`?

Comment: @Fravadona, here is the link that can explain it more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932996/what-is-the-meaning-of-0-0-in-awk

Comment: The trailing `1` is just a shortcut for `print`, the `$1=$1` has to do with field splitting/formatting.

Answer (score 1):

A quick one:

```
$  sed 's/./&\n/g' <<<"HELLO"
H
E
L
L
O
```

Answer (score 1):

with [fold](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/fold-invocation.html)

```sh
$ echo hello | fold -w1
h
e
l
l
o
```

Answer (score 0):

with perl5:

```
echo "HELLO" | perl -ne 'chomp; print $_,$/ for split""'
H
E
L
L
O
```